# Is there a special case where we must use ModelState.IsValid rather than TryUpdateModel or vice versa?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am really confused to choose either `ModelState.IsValid` or `TryUpdateModel` to use in my `Create`, `Edit` , and `Delete` action method (HTTP-POST).

Is there a special case where we must use `ModelState.IsValid` rather than `TryUpdateModel` or vice versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TryUpdateModel` function returns `ModelState.IsValid`. That is one. With `TryUpdateModel` you can update existing object with values provided in form. But when you create a new one, you have two ways:

```
[HttpPost]
public function Create(Model model)
{
      //ModelState is already populated, binding of form values to Model is done.
}
```

or

```
[HttpPost]
public function Create()
{
    //ModelState is not populated yet
    var model = new Model();
    TryUpdateModel(model);
    //ModelState is populated here, after Model values population.
}
```

When you update existing model, it can look like that:

```
[HttpPost]
public function Update(int id)
{
    var model = Repository.Get(id);
    TryUpdateModel(model);
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
        Repository.Save();
}
```

or

```
[HttpPost]
public function Update(int id)
{
    var model = Repository.Get(id);
    if (TryUpdateModel(model))
        Repository.Save();
}
```

This is the same.

Comment: Your 3rd and 4th code above show `[HttpPost] Update` with `int id` parameter. I think they will NOT compile because their signatures are exactly the same as `[HttpGet] Update`.

Comment: @user596314: Yes, it will not, because this was just example. It is more common to use `[HttpPost] public function Update(ViewModel model)` function header and then transfer values from model to model loaded from database, just like you did in another question.

Comment: How do you know whether `ModelState` has been or have not been populated? Do you have  good learning references (e.g., books, blogs, etc) for me to read? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @user596314: http://www.asp.net/mvc has a lot of materials, really. For example this http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1. I used tutorial from this site to learn basics.